# How can i call a class from a different jar file?

Tags: java, methods, jar

If I have a program with several jars, how can I call classes which are in another jar?

Comment: Add it to your classpath?

Comment: Could you please explain how ?

Comment: java -cp <jars> should do the trick. No ?

Comment: If the jar is already added as a dependency or library, then you can import the class into your java file and call the class.

Answer (score 0):

Add the jar in your project classpath and import the class in your code

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to compile you application with the jars together, and simply import the class you are going to instantiate in your code.

`javac` looks for the classes being imported in the classpath, check the `-cp` option

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. If you're looking to use classes that are in multiple jars, just place all of the jars on your application's classpath.  If you're running into package naming conflicts (i.e. you have one class that is being loaded by multiple jars), then you might need to write your own class loader to solve this.

Comment: For instance i want to call a class that is in jar A from a class that is in jar B